# Fortify reports a dynamic code evaluation vulnerability

Tags: javascript, security, fortify

Fortify is reporting a dynamic code evaluation vulnerability in one of my JavaScripts. The particular line builds a URL and I am not sure as to what is risky about this. Can someone please point that out. Below is the code.

```
ProxyCollector.doAjax=function(k,l){var j=document.location.protocol+"//"+k+":"+getRandomPort()+"/NonExistentImage"+getRandomPort()+".gif";
```

This is the Abstract from the fortify report:
The file test.js interprets unvalidated user input as source code on line 315.
Interpreting user-controlled instructions at run-time can allow attackers to execute
malicious code.

Comment: How is `ProxyCollector.doAjax` called? Show the example of usage. Also, show the continuation of this function. How is `j` variable called then? Too few code provided.

Comment: Probably just a false-positive on the use of `location`. Searching suggests this tool is not very bright.